# why images aren't stored in public path

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I am a Laravel beginner and I want to build an API with Laravel 8.

I have `posts` and `images` and I want to *store* and *update* them.

My `store` method works and the *images* are saved in the database and `public` path in images folders, but in `update` method I can't save it in folder.

These are my codes:

#### `PostController`

```php
public function store(Request $request )
{
    $data = $request->all();

    //validationg posts and images fields
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required|max:150|unique:posts',
        'body' => 'required',
        'study_time' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'nullable|string',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'خطا در اعتبار سنجی']);
    }

    //separate tags
    $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

    if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
        //getting post images from request
        $files = $request->file('image');

        //saving name and path of images
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $imageName = time().rand(1,10000).'.'.$file->extension();
            $postTitle = $request->title; //post title for folder name and the images inside it
            $imagePath = public_path(). '/images/posts/'.$postTitle;

            $file->move($imagePath, $imageName);

            $image = new Image;
            $image->image = $imageName;
            $image->path = $imagePath;

            $images[] = $image; // make an array of uploaded images
        }
    }

    $post = Post::create($data);
    $post->images()->saveMany($images);//save imageas in image table
    $post->tag($tags);//save tags in tags table

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'با موفقیت ثبت گردید ',
        'data' => $post
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post_failed = Post::find($id);
    if (is_null($post_failed)) {
        return response()->json('پست  مورد نظر یافت نشد ', 404);
    }

    $data = $request->all();

    //validation posts and images fields
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required|max:150|unique:posts',
        'body' => 'required',
        'study_time' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'nullable|string',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors(), 'خطا در اعتبار سنجی ']);
    }

    $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);

    if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
        $postTitle = $request->title; //post title for folder name and the images inside it

        //delete last Images from database for updating images
        Image::where('imageable_type', 'App\Models\Post')->where('imageable_id' , $id)->delete();

        //delete last images images folder
        File::delete(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle));

        $files = $request->file('image');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $imageName = time().rand(1,10000).'.'.$file->extension();
            $imagePath = public_path(). '/images/posts/'.$postTitle;

            $image = new Image();
            $image->image = $imageName;
            $image->path = $imagePath;
            $images[] = $image;
        }
    }

    $post = Post::find($id);

    $post->user_id = $data['user_id'];
    $post->category_id = $data['category_id'];
    $post->title = $data['title'];
    $post->body = $data['body'];
    $post->study_time = $data['study_time'];
    $post->tags = $data['tags'];

    $post->save();
    $post->images()->saveMany($images);
    $post->tag($tags);


    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'با موفقیت ویرایش گردید ',
        'data' => $post
    ]);
}
```

The relation between `posts` and `images` is `polymorphic` one to many and I tested it with postman.

#### Postman

[image]

#### Database

[image]

[image]

And the path:

[image]

Please, help.

Comment: "but in update method I can't save it in folder." explain this. It goes somewhere else, nowhere, is there a error, some warning in logs, any other info?

Comment: i mean the images  i uploaded , aren't store in public path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `store()` method you saved images on disk by using

```
$imagePath = public_path(). '/images/posts/'.$postTitle;
$file->move($imagePath, $imageName);
```

In `update()` you deleted them

```
File::delete(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle));
```

and determined path for new files

```
$imagePath = public_path(). '/images/posts/'.$postTitle;
```

but nothing happens after this. In whole `update()` method there is no code that could do something in storage, so of course nothing appears in folder ;)

So again use `$file->move()` or `Storage` facade to save files.

#### TIP

Also this is bad practice to repeat long code logic like that. It would be better to extract this and share between store/update.

Comment: if i delete this line `File::delete(public_path('/images/posts/'.$postTitle));` nothing appears again.   this `FILE::DLETE` doesn't work at all